# why is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(3\log2)^n}{(n+1)!}$ = 8 GRE subject problem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(3\log2)^n}{(n+1)!} = 8 $$

Hi,
this is from the GRE subject practice test. I know the answer but don't understand why it is so..

My guess is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{x^n}{n!}= e^x$  so $e^{3\log2}= e^{\log(2^3)}=8$.

I tried
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(3\log2)^n}{(n+1)!} =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(3\log2)^{n-1}}{(n)!}$

but wasn't able to seperate 1 from $(3\log2)^{n-1}$ to get  something like
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is wrong. We have
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(3\ln 2) ^n}{(n+1)! }&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(3\ln 2) ^{n-1}}{n! }\\
&=\frac{1}{3\ln 2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(3\ln 2) ^{n}}{n! }\\
&=\frac{1}{3\ln 2}\left(-\frac{(3\ln 2)^0}{0!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(3\ln 2) ^{n}}{n! }\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{3\ln 2}(-1+8) \\
&=\frac{7}{3\ln 2}<8.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: (+1) By the way, I guess you made a type in the first step: $(n+1)!$ in the RHS of the first line should be $n!$.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, I correct it

Comment: This answer is exactly what I got before I even looked at Jochen's answer.

Answer (score 1):

$e^x = \sum \dfrac{x^n}{n!}$, and not $\sum \dfrac{x}{n!}$

That should help.

Answer (score 1):

It strongly appears that somewhere, something got copied incorrectly.
@Jochen gave the correct answer to the question as it stands currently.
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(3\ln 2) ^n}{(n+1)!} = \frac{7}{2\ln 2}$$

However, if the denominator in the original series is $n!$ instead of $(n+1)!$, the 8 listed as the answer in OP's question becomes correct.
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(3\ln 2) ^n}{(n)!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x ^n}{n!} =e^{\ln 2^3}=8$$ using $x=3\ln 2 = \ln 8.$

Note: Throughout this question and these answers, $\log y$ is interpreted as $\log y = \ln y = \log_e y$

Comment: Yes the question was $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(3\ln 2) ^n}{(n)!}$ ..   https://www.ets.org/gre/test-takers/subject-tests/about/content-structure.html#accordion-792530b110-item-ab30804f15          problem#2  from pdf here  .      Thank you for correcting!